# how to find Second char from a special char in sql

Tags: sql-server, function, substring, charindex

i have this= 'student 1-99-98 - 281 - 1567519464'
an this length is dynamic i want Phrase of after last '-'
i want to extract this='1567519464'
please help me in Microsoft SQL query

Comment: something like `select substring(*string*, 1, charindex('-')) as result`?

Comment: edited please check again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Ltrim(rtrim(RIGHT('student 1-99-98 - 281 - 1567519464', (CHARINDEX('-',REVERSE('student 1-99-98 - 281 - 1567519464'),0)-1))))
```